Webpack hot-reload or react-refresh-webpack-plugin not working
Trying to migrate an old react app to React 17 & Webpack 5, the app is loading now but hot-reload or react refresh webpack plugin is not working.
As soon as there's a change, the page crash and shows an error 'Cannot GET /{whatever route was reloaded}.
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

const isProduction = process.argv.indexOf('-p') >= 0 || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './src');
const outPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist');

const API_HOST_NAME = isProduction ? env.API_URL_PRODUCTION : env.API_URL_DEVELOPMENT;
console.log(API_HOST_NAME);

const envKeys = {
  // Other environment variables...
};

const config = {
  context: sourcePath,
  entry: {
    app: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000', // Webpack Dev Server client to listen for updates
      'webpack/hot/dev-server', // HMR runtime for hot reloading
      './main.tsx' // Your application entry point
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: outPath,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js', // Unique names for chunks
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    clean: true
  },
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: ['node_modules', './src'],
    mainFields: ['module', 'browser', 'main'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'), // Sets @ as an alias for the src directory
      '@screens': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@screens'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@hooks'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@components'),
      '@reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@reducers'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@assets'),
      '@interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@interfaces'),
      '@services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@services'),
      '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@store'),
      ReactDOM: '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // TypeScript Loader
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/, // Matches .ts and .tsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Exclude node_modules for performance
        use: 'ts-loader' // Use ts-loader to transpile TypeScript
      },
      // JavaScript and JSX Loader (Babel)
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // Matches .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Exclude node_modules for performance
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'), // Use Babel to transpile JS/JSX
            options: {
              plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', // Support optional chaining in JS
                !isProduction && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')
              ].filter(Boolean),
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env', // Transpile modern JS to ES5 for compatibility
                '@babel/preset-react' // Transpile JSX to JavaScript
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true // Enables Babel caching for faster builds
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      // CSS Loader
      {
        test: /\.css$/, // Matches .css files
        use: [
          'style-loader', // Injects CSS into the DOM
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true // Enables source maps for CSS files
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        type: 'asset/resource' // Webpack 5 handles `.ico` files using the asset/resource type
      },
      // Asset Loader (Images, Fonts, Media)
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/, // Matches various asset types
        type: 'asset', // Automatically decides whether to inline or emit file
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024 // Inline assets smaller than 10KB, emit larger files
          }
        }
      },
      // HTML Loader
      {
        test: /\.html$/, // Matches .html files
        use: 'html-loader' // Exports HTML as a string
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys), // Define custom environment variables
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development', // NODE_ENV is set only here to avoid conflict
      DEBUG: false
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[contenthash].css',
      disable: !isProduction
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      favicon: '@assets/favicon.ico',
      template: '@assets/index.html'
    }),
    !isProduction && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-store' // Prevent caching during development
    },
    // static: isProduction ? outPath : sourcePath,
    static: {
      directory: isProduction ? outPath : sourcePath
    },
    hot: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 8000, // Port your app runs on
    client: {
      overlay: !isProduction,
      logging: isProduction ? 'none' : 'warn'
    }
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map'
};

module.exports = config;

I am thinking it might be something related to ts-loader but not really sure.
I am using the @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin library which is also the library that CRA uses.
